# Calling Correct Database Table with Laravel all()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am just getting started with Laravel 5. I am trying to set up a basic page that retrieves all data from a database table. I have a table call people and I have a controller called ContactController.php. The controller has the following code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Contact;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $people = Contact::all();

        return $people;

    }
}
```

When I access my page, I get the following error:

```
QueryException in /home/vagrant/sites/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php line 614:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.contacts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `contacts`)
```

Why is it trying to access homestead.contacts? My table is called people. I never created a table called contacts. Where is it drawing the table name from and how do I correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: What table is your `Contact.php` class model using?

Comment: I think you first should check your model `Contact` as suggested.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't properly configured your database. Take a look at the `config/database.php` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage):

> Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our User model. The lower-case, plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified.

So if you define nothing else, Laravel will take the plural snake_case version of your class name:

```
Contact      =>     contacts
FooBar       =>     foo_bars
```

To fix your issue either change the model name accordingly. In this case `Person` will let Laravel search for the table `people`.

Or explicitly specify the table in your model:

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'people';
}
```

Comment: If I can chime in, if you have multiple databases with the same table, you can also tell the model what connection to use via `protected $connection = "connection_name";`

Comment: This solved my problem. I did not have anything configured in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right table name in your `app/Contact.php` model?

```
protected $table = 'people';
```

Or are you using the wrong model?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your Contact model (app/Contact.php).

```
protected $table = 'people';
```

This will work.